# MySQL: Have unique values in a column with one exception

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-clause

I've created a column of usernames but the ids for each row is linked to another table. If a user is deleted, I'd like to change the username to 'Deleted'. So I'd like to allow for unique values except for a deleted user.

I've come across this solution:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_user
ON User(Username)
WHERE Username != 'Deleted';
```

But MySQL throws an error saying "`WHERE` is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'". Does MySQL not allow for the `WHERE` clause for a `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` statement? Is there another way that having all unique values except one is possible?

Comment: Better have a boolean `active` field, or a second `deleted_users` table...

Comment: also you can have second column where you can save the deleted name

Comment: Thanks @moonwave99 ! I think I'll go with a deleted_users table because I want usernames to be reusable if a user has deleted their account. Otherwise, they're unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `UNIQUE` index on `Username` when it's not `Deleted` and `NULL` otherwise, using the fact that `NULL` is not equal with itself to your advantage:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_user
ON `User`((CASE WHEN  Username = 'Deleted' THEN null ELSE Username END));
```

Comment: That's much simpler than my suggestion. +1

Answer (score 2):

The task is addressing the scenario where you must keep data, but it needs to be anonymized. E.g. you need to know that some user ordered product xy in January 2017, but laws force you to become oblivious to which user that was.

MySQL does not support conditional indexes (indexes with a `WHERE` clause). But you can create a function index including the ID when a user is deleted:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_user
  ON User(Username, (CASE WHEN  Username = 'Deleted' THEN id ELSE 0 END));
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/HDWnVeKl